# Issue with merging of rows in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

[image]

I have tried this below code

```
select STUFF((
        select ',' + t1 Issue
        from Log_table  t1
        where t1.VID= t.VID
        for xml path(''), type  
       ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')  Cmnts,
       Main_table .vehical_id, name, location,
from Log_table t RIGHT JOIN
     main_table
     on VID = vehicle_id
group by t.VID, Vehicle_id, name, location**
```

after running the query the data in "issue" column is not in proper order.
means for example  for vehicle_id-333  [image].

how make correct allignment for this.

thanks.

Comment: If you want the comments in a certain order, then you need to add an order by to your subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you referring to the `log_table` twice?

Second, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a separate column to specify the ordering.  Let me assume that you have a `log_id` column in the `leg_table` with this information:

```
select STUFF((select ',' + t.Issue
              from Log_table t
              where t.VID = m.VID
              order by t.log_id  -- Assumes you have an id or some column for ordering
              for xml path(''), type  
             ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''
            )  Cmnts, m.vehicle_id, m.name, m.location,
from main_table m;
```

I removed the `group by`, because you probably don't need that.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your quick response. I have tried this but the records in the column is not in correct order . it Suppose to comment1 , comment2 and comment3 . But  it is coming in comment3 , comment1  and Comment 2.plz assist me .

Comment: @shaikahamad . . . As I say in the answer, you need a column to specify the ordering . . . and id or date or something.

Comment: Hi Gordan, need some more info, can we make the comments in seperate lines

Answer (score 0):

please try below query. below we are introducing `ORDER` over comment field.
demo sql fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/981c34/1

```
select  
m.vehicle_id, 
m.name, 
m.location,
STUFF(
        (
            select ',' + t.issue from
                    (
                        select *, 
                            row_number() over (partition by vid order by issue asc) as r 
                        from Log_table 
                    ) t
            where t.VID= m.vehicle_id 
                order by t.r
            for xml path(''), type  
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')  
        Cmnts
from
     main_table m
```